# Install mdatp 404 not found

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation

I'm following a [Microsoft guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/linux-install-manually?view=o365-worldwide#application-installation) for installing `mdatp` (Microsoft Defender) and I'm ending up with a `404 Not Found` when doing the `apt install mdatp`. I'm on Ubuntu 21.04 and I'm using a `insider-fast.list` with (note the 20.04 being used):

```
deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod insiders-fast main
```

Doing `sudo apt install mdatp` I end up with the following result:

```
...
After this operation, 153 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod insiders-fast/main amd64 mdatp amd64 101.32.55-insiderfast
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.214.230.139 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/m/mdatp/mdatp_101.32.55-insiderfast.amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 104.214.230.139 443]
```

I've successfully done this with Ubuntu 20.04 at a earlier time, but now I'm on 21.04 with the 20.04 list. The `404` looks real, but I'm unsure where the issue lies. Is their software repo out of order?

Comment: It appears the repo was broken. The `pool` folder has now reappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository seems to be out of order: there should be a `pool` directory [here](https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/), alongside `dists`.

This is being tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6381). See also [this Ars Technica article on the outage](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/06/microsofts-linux-repositories-were-down-for-18-hours/).